# I don't see output statistic from gather_index_stats. Where can I find this?

Tags: oracle, indexing, statistics

```
create index test_kol2_idx on test (kol2);
-- statystyki
begin
dbms_stats.gather_index_stats(ownname => 'c##wojtek_admin', indname => 'test_kol2_idx');
end;
```

I can't find the statistic from gather_index_stats in SQL Developer. I want to check if my index improves the speed of the select statement.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`dba_indexes` will have some statistics.

If you want to know if it improves the speed of your SQL statement then you should run that statement and see if it’s faster.

Comment: But I can't find the output from : "dbms_stats.gather_index_stats(ownname => 'c##wojtek_admin', indname => 'test_kol2_idx');"

Comment: Looks like you’re missing a new line with '/' in your script to actually submit the pl/sql command. Now that you’ve shared the statement, why do you think that index would help? Additionally, when you create an index, so long as you’re on a version of at least 10g (out of support for a long time), Oracle will be gathering index statistics for you.

Comment: Where should I add a new line?  I  created a simple table to find out how it works. I know that this index doesn't improve the speed.

Comment: At the end of your pl/sql anonymous block, see https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/tutorial_KS0KNKP218J86THKN85XU37.html see how all these anonymous blocks end with a '/' on a new line to submit the command to the database.